# PowerShell error-checking/logging

Tags: powershell, error-handling, error-logging

I have the following powershell script that cycles through a list of files and renames them.  I'd like incorporate some error checking and logging on the exception(s) below:

> Exception calling "GetFile" with "1" argument(s): "There is no Web
>   named "/cmms"." At C:\eam\Exportjbh.ps1:18 char:22
>   +     $file = $web.GetFile <<<< ($FullPath)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:\eam\Exportjbh.ps1:19 char:35
>   +         $binary = $file.OpenBinary <<<< ()
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (OpenBinary:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Write" and the argument count:
>   "1". At C:\eam\Exportjbh.ps1:27 char:22
>   +         $writer.write <<<< ($binary)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
>
> ```
> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
>
> $Url = "https://....."
> $UrlSub = "docs"
> $FullPath = $Url + $UrlSub
> $destinationFolder = "c:\022713\"
> $sourceCsv = "c:\filename.CSV"
>
> $Site = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite $Url 
> $web =  $Site.OpenWeb($UrlSub)
> $fileObjects = Import-CSV $sourceCsv 
>
> ForEach ($fileObject in $fileObjects) 
> {
>     $fileUrl = $fileObject.DOC_FILENAME.replace($Url,"")
>     $file = $web.GetFile($FullPath)
>         $binary = $file.OpenBinary()
>
>     $dateTimeStamp = Get-Date -format s
>     $newFileName = $fileObject.DocumentType + "_" + $fileObject.SAPObjectNumber + "_" +
> ```
>
> $dateTimeStamp.replace(":","").replace("-","")
>           $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($file.Name)
>
> ```
>     $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream(($destinationfolder + $newFileName + $extension), [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
>     $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
>     $writer.write($binary)
>     $writer.Close() } $web.Dispose()
> ```

Comment: Have you experimented with the TRY-CATCH blocks?

Comment: `Try...Catch` is the way to go for this.  As written this is way too broad though.  Please add some specifics.